# Is there any way to find package name of a given procedure in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, package, procedure

Is there any way to find package name of a given procedure in oracle 11g.

regards,
Tarak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `USER_PROCEDURES` view as it contains the package name in the `OBJECT_NAME` column and procedure within it in the `PROCEDURE_NAME` column for records having `OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE'`.

Use the following query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME AS PACKAGE_NAME,
       PROCEDURE_NAME
  FROM USER_PROCEDURES
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PACKAGE'
   AND PROCEDURE_NAME = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME';
```

Comment: Thanks Tejash ! I got the result.

Comment: Still, guys, this won't find **private** procedures/functions (the ones that are declared only within the package body, and not exposed in package specification.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do that:

```
select *
from user_source
where lower(text) like '%my_procedure%'
  and type = 'PACKAGE BODY';
```

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot ! I got the result